# How can I turn an array to csv file in php

Tags: php, csv

One more beginner question:
how can I turn an array (actually it's just a text) like that:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => nsor@cg.ukrtel.net
        [1] => p2007@rambler.ru
        [2] => pan20072009@yandex.ru
        [3] => gf@ukr.net
        [4] => tmkp@ma.odessa.ua
        [5] => export@soh.by
        [6] => advert@soh.by
    )
)
```

into a .csv file by means of PHP? This file should be without things like this "[0] =>", only addresses.

Comment: By writing some code ;) What have you tried so far? Maybe this helps: http://php.net/manual/de/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: With only 1 field per line now, the `implode` below works fine. If you need more fields per line, look at `fputcsv()`.

Comment: -1 for not doing your homework!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your array is in a variable called `$arr`, you could use

```
echo implode("\r\n",$arr);
```

And you  might want to prefix it with

```
header('Content-type: text-csv; charset="UTF-8"');
```

or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the first example at http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Use your array instead of the array in the example.